# How can we identify Site Template and Page Template information in Liferay DB

Tags: liferay

I have created page templates and site templates. I want to assign the site template dynamically to the community based on the user role.

How can I achieve it through code.

From which table i can get the site template and page template information.

If I know the details of templates then i can assign it to community dynamically.

Need solution.

Answer (score 4):

`Page template` is stored in `LayoutPrototype` table.

`Site template` is stored in `LayoutsetPrototype` table.

Comment: Just make sure you get the information using the *LocalServiceUtil classes, and not direct queries to the DB.